# How can I show Git submodules indented and underneath their parent repository in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-submodules

Is there a way or maybe even an extension to tell VS Code, to display in the source control view the loaded submodules of a repository indented and underneath the corresponding repository?

I have for example 3 repositories which are numerically labeled. They all have two submodules of the same repository and it would be awesome if VS Code would display them like this in the source control view:

```
Repo1
  SubmoduleXY
  ZubmoduleA
Repo2
  SubmoduleXY
  ZubmoduleA
Repo3
  SubmoduleXY
  ZubmoduleA
```

However, what I see is:

```
Repo1
Repo2
Repo3
SubmoduleXY
SubmoduleXY
SubmoduleXY
ZubmoduleA
ZubmoduleA
ZubmoduleA
```

So by looking only at the source control view I have no clue which submodule belongs to which repository.

I tried to search for a solution, but the only thing I was able to find was how to hide/disable submodules in the source control view entirely.

Comment: Feature request: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197819

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would either need to [find](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) or [write an extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) to get such a feature, or [write a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) in the VS Code GitHub repo for this. I am not aware of such a feature for vanilla VS Code (I'd be happy to be proven mistaken though). <s>I tried googling for an existing feature-request with "`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues "feature-request" git submodule nest source control view`", but I didn't find anything.</s> Feature request has now been raised at [Show submodules indented to the belonging repository #197819](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/197819).